# Perform Realm migration from one List to another updating property value

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-migration

I'm trying to count how many cards are equal inside my List and update the new quantity property with the count number

> eg:
>
> newObject!["list"] = [CardObject1, CardObject2, CardObject2,
>   CardObject2, CardObject3, CardObject3]
>
> Assign to temporary list
>
> var tempList = List()
>
> CardObject1 (Update quantity property to 1)
>   CardObject2 (Update quantity property to 3)
>   CardObject3 (Update quantity property to 2)
>
> tempList = [CardObject1, CardObject2, CardObject3]
>
> Assign back to newObject!["list"] the updated/migrated list
>
> newObject!["list"] = newList

Crash at **newList.index(of: card)**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object type 'CardDTO' does not match RLMArray type 'DynamicObject'.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

**Info:**

DeckDTO.swift

```
class DeckDTO: Object {
dynamic var id = NSUUID().uuidString
dynamic var name = ""
var list = List<CardDTO>()

  override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "id"
  }
}
```

CardDTO.swift

```
class CardDTO: Object, Mappable {

// Other properties
dynamic var id = NSUUID().uuidString
dynamic var quantity: Int = 1
// Other properties

 required convenience public init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
    mapping(map: map)
 }

 func mapping(map: Map) {
    //Map all my properties
 }

 override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "id"
 }
}
```

**What I'm trying**

```
if oldSchemaVersion < 2 {
  migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: CardDTO.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
    newObject!["quantity"] = 1
  }

  migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: DeckDTO.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
    var newList = List<DynamicObject>()
    let oldList = newObject!["list"] as! List<DynamicObject>
    for card in oldList {
        if let i = newList.index(of: card), i >= 0 {
            newList[i] = (newList[i] as! CardDTO).quantity += 1 //some how do quantity++
            print("increment quantity")
        } else {
            newList.append(card)
        }
    }
    newObject!["list"] = newList
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm migration blocks (and their dynamic API) aren't really well-suited for your particular use case. Neither `index(of:)` nor `append()` can be used properly with dynamic objects.

My recommendation for approaching this problem is to simply set the `quantity` properties to 1 in the migration block as you are doing, and then set a boolean flag that indicates that you need to perform the deck update. Then, before you do anything else (perhaps in `application(_: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`), open the Realm and check for that flag. If that flag is set you can then open the Realm and perform the migration using the normal Realm API.

Here is some example code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Get the configuration and set the migration block on it
    var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
    config.schemaVersion = 2
    var needsMigrationToV2 = false

    config.migrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 2 {
            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: CardDTO.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                newObject!["quantity"] = 1
            }
            needsMigrationToV2 = true
        }
    }
    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
    // Run the rest of the migration using the typed API
    if needsMigrationToV2 {
        let allDecks = realm.objects(DeckDTO.self)
        try! realm.write {
            for deck in allDecks {
                var uniqueCards : [CardDTO] = []
                for card in deck.list {
                    if uniqueCards.contains(card) {
                        card.quantity += 1
                    } else {
                        uniqueCards.append(card)
                    }
                }
                deck.list.removeAll()
                deck.list.append(objectsIn: uniqueCards)
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

One more thing to note is that `List<T>` properties should be declared as `let`, not `var`, since reassigning to a `List<T>` property is an error.